# Are there 2 Laylatul Qadr or just one?

Tags: ramadan, laylat-al-qadr, moon

We all know that Laylatul Qadr is in one of the last 5 odd nights of Ramadan (21st, 23rd, 25th, 27th or 29th). And as Allah SWT explains it's significance in Quran as

> The night of Al-Qadr is better than a thousand months [Al-Qadr 97:3]

Also Allaw SWT explains that angels decends on this night in the same Surah.

As there are different islamic dates around the globe. For example, if **Saudi Arabia has 20th Ramadan** night today, **in Pakistan we will have 19th night**. So when it will be **21st night in Saudi Arabia**, it will be 20th night in Pakistan. If let's say this year Laylatul Qadr comes on 21st night, we will have 20th night in Pakistan. Now my question is, **will there be 2 laylatul Qadars**. **One on 21st night in Saudi Arabia and one on 21st night in Pakistan (which will be the next night)** or there will be only one and the people in Pakistan will have to look it in the even nights.
Will angels come on 2 different nights or just one night? Can anybody please explain? This question is in my mind since childhood and I never got a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The knowledge of laylat al-Qadr is by Allah all information we have from hadith are based on ijtihad of sahabah and some blury hints of the prophet and we know ijtihad doesn't necessarily mean that the result is correct.

Comment: Sheikh Asim Al Hakeem answers [this question](https://youtu.be/BXHIetZ8SN4)

Comment: Maybe my answer on [Why is laylatul qadr to be the 27th night of Ramadan?](https://islam.stackexchange.com commonly thought/questions/1227/why-is-laylatul-qadr-commonly-thought-to-be-the-27th-night-of-ramadan) is a bit of help.

Comment: The concept of time is limited to this world. God created time and is beyond it. I recommend you to look into the Space-Time Continuum concept and how our idea of time is affected by our point of reference.